# Only submit last AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following code runs when the user submits a form:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this);
   $('#yes').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      submit(form);
   });
});
```

which works, sort of.

However, if you user repeatedly clicks "Submit" then these submits seem to get queued and then when the user clicks the "yes" button, **all** the queued submissions get submitted.

I just want the last form submission to get submitted to the server when the user clicks "yes".

How do you do this?  Maybe I need a `return false`, `e.preventDefault()` or `e.preventPropagation` somewhere?

Comment: Maybe you could disable the submit button after in the submit handler?

Comment: $('#yes').off('click') in the end of submit event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted your ajax code but this is what you could do:

```
$('#yes').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   submit(form);
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

and then in your ajax success function you can enable it this way:

```
$.ajax({
  ......
  success: function(){
     $('#yes').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

---

#### Note:

But this won't submit multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to use a variable which checks if a request is underway?

```
var request_processing = false;

$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this);
   $('#yes').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      if (request_processing) {
         return;
      }

      request_processing = true;

      submit(form); // Set it to false once the request is complete.
   });
});
```

An alternative route could be to disable the button once the first click is done, this would also indicate to the user that it is being processed, maybe adding a small loading gif next to it. Then renable the button once the request is done.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the form is submitted, you are binding a new function to the yes button click event. So, when you do click the yes button, all of the functions are run.

Instead, try creating the event listener just once on the yes button, outside of the form submit event:

```
$('#yes').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   var form = $('#myForm');
   submit(form); // I assume this is the function that makes the ajax request
});
```

You should still prevent the default event on the form, and depending on how your form works, you may wish to add the commented behaviour:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // validate all required fields
    // then show/enable 'yes' button (you could disable submit button too)
}
```